# Save ansible variable in local file

Tags: ansible

I am executing a PS script on a windows host and want to store its stdout in a file on an ansible local machine. I have a playbook like following:

```yaml
---
- name: Check Antivirus software
  hosts: all
  become: false
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - name: Get AV details
      win_shell: |
        echo "script printing data on stdout"
      register: result
    - name: save response
      copy:
        content: '{{ result.stdout }}'
        dest: '{{ response_file }}'
      delegate_to: localhost
```

From the above playbook, 1st task gets executed without any issues. But 2nd task gives the following error.

```
TASK [save response] *******************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [20.15.102.192 -> localhost]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "ntlm: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=5986): Max retries exceeded with url: /wsman (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f4940760208>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))", "unreachable": true}
```

I also tried local_action which is also giving the same error.

Comment: Have an inventory file that has `localhost connection=local`.  It's trying to connection with WinRM.

Comment: The inventory is generated dynamically by python code. Is there any way to change connection=local for this particular task

Comment: How are you specifying your inventory in the run?

Comment: Let's say you have `inventory/dynamic.py`.  Create the file `inventory/static.inv` and put `localhost connection=local` in it.  Then use `ansible-playbook -i inventory`.

Comment: Can you please show your inventory? As already pointed out by Jack, you have declared localhost explicitly rather than relying on [implicit localhost](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory/implicit_localhost.html) and that it now it matches some connection vars declared in your inventory file and uses the `winrm` connection rather that the default `local` connection.

Answer (score 0):

use fetch_module instead of copy_module
and than you might not need "delegate_to: localhost" aymore

```
- name: save response
  ansible.builtin.fetch:
    content: '{{ result.stdout }}'
    dest: '{{ response_file }}'
```